# Binary tree: how to change every leaf value to the sum of the path to it

Tags: python

I'm trying to change the leaves' values to the sums of the paths to them (without returning anything).
I tried using recursion, however I'm not sure at which point in the code I should call the set function and how to make sure it only changes the leaves . This is what I've tried so far:

```
class Node:

    def __init__(self, value, left=None, right=None):
        self.__value = value
        self.__left = left
        self.__right = right

    def get_left(self):
        return self.__left

    def get_right(self):
        return self.__right

    def get_value(self):
        return self.__value

    def set_value(self, value):
        self.__value = value


def sum_to_leaves(node):
    if node is None:
        return
    new_value = node.get_value() + sum_to_leaves(node.get_left()) + sum_to_leaves(node.get_right())
    if node.get_left() is None and node.get_right() is None:
        node.set_value(new_value)
        return
```

Answer (score 1):

Compute the path sum on your way *down*, passing it as parameter.

```
def sum_to_leaves(node, path_sum=0):
    if node:
        path_sum += node.get_value()
        sum_to_leaves(node.get_left(), path_sum)
        sum_to_leaves(node.get_right(), path_sum) 
        if node.get_left() is node.get_right():
            node.set_value(path_sum)
```